# .NET Core 2.1 Azure Functions won't build in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops

I keep getting this error when I try to run the pipelines for my azure backend functions:

> [error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.27\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): Error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
>
> The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found.

It's a pretty old program, but yesterday was the first time that the build has failed and I don't know how to fix it. It happens both in the develop and main branch so I'm guessing it's a change from Azure.

Comment: .NET Core 2.1 [reached End-of-Life in August 2021](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-august-21-2021/). This wasn't a sudden announcement, the [.NET Core support policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) was published years in advance. The current Long-Term-Support versions are 3.1 and 6, with 3.1 reaching EOL on May 2022

Comment: It looks like Azure Devops kept supporting the obsolete .NET Core version for a full 6 months after it was discontinued to allow people to migrate. That grace period expired. You'll have to migrate. The current LTS version is .NET 6. .NET Core 3.1 reaches EOL on December 2022, so it's not worth migrating to it

Comment: Are you sure your Azure Function is still running as 2.1? [According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#pinning-to-version-20) all 2.x versions were automatically migrated to 3.1 unless they were pinned to 2.2

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can i see this in the azure portal? Localy everything is stil running on dotnet 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/4871) .NET Core 2.1 has been removed from all build agent images.

> #### Possible impact
>
> If your project depends on a pre-installed .Net 2.1 it can be broken.

You can try to use the [setup dotnet task](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet) to explicitly install .NET Core 2.1.

```
- uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
  with:
    dotnet-version: '2.1.x'
```

Please be advised .NET Core 2.1 has been out of support since August 21, 2021 (see [.NET and .NET Core Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)). An upgrade to a currently supported version like .NET Core 3.1 or higher should not be a lot of work and is well worth the effort.

[image: Chart showing .NET Core 3.1 as an LTS release that happened in December 2019 and all other releases happening in November starting with .NET 5 and intercalating between Current and LTS]

Comment: 3.1 isn't a real option either, as it reaches EOL on December 2022

Comment: Although true, it might be a give-us-some-breathing-room-now option, enabling a migration to an even newer version of .NET later on in the year. But, agreed, if I were upgrading now I would upgrade to .NET 6 taking into account that .NET 5 reaches end of support even sooner, on May 8, 2022.

Comment: Yes, but updating the project I'm working on from 2.1 to 5 will probably taker some work, so if this is the case then I kind of just want my job to scrap the project (its old been going on since 2018) and starting it over with new good techknowlogy, is there any way you can stil get it to run in the pipelines?

Comment: @ChristineGarcia please see my answer, and then especially the [setup dotnet task](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet) part.

Comment: That may not help, as the project probably runs on .NET Core 3.1 already. As [the docs explain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#pinning-to-version-20) `.NET function apps running on version 2.x (~2) are automatically upgraded to run on .NET Core 3.1`. The project may *already* be running as .NET Core 3.1. Why not change the target version from `netcore2.0` to `netcore3.1` and see if it builds?

Comment: It will still work as of now with the fix above, but I gues sthe problem is I don't know how long that fix will work. @PanagiotisKanavos